# CI/CD in Java vs Salesforce

Tags: continuous-integration

CI/CD in terms is the same for Java and Salesforce, but in depth what exactly are the differences between them in CI and CD pipelines? For example: in a Java CD pipeline, they have to go see a lot of stuffs, like proper Infrastructure, Network Connection etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI/CD in Salesforce is simply difficult to implement. SalesforceDX, a new way to manage the platform's metadata, is the way to go to work with CI/CD pipelines in Salesforce right now.

In the vast majority of Java projects, it can be built and have its unit tests ran locally, while this isn't true for Salesforce. So the main difference is that a Java project probably won't rely on the server (like Salesforce) to build and test the project.

On a Salesforce CI/CD pipeline you will have to configure the project to create a scratch org, push the source code to it, then run all the Apex unit tests (and since we are talking CI/CD, you can probably get a tool to run integration and unit tests as well). Java projects, like I said, can be tested locally most of the times (without uploading/downloading something from a remote server). On Salesforce, you'll have to wait for your code to upload and compile, then wait for it to have the tests run.

I didn't understand what you meant for "proper Infrastructure, Network Connection", but I think those are tests that your Java project has to run to check if it will run successfully on the server (like a maximum memory test, maybe? or a test that checks how much time a request takes to be processed). On Salesforce I don't think you'll have to worry about this, since all your Apex code will have to be tested for deployment anyway (and this involves testing callout methods - here the "network" stuff - and checking if the business rules run correctly).

tl;dr: Since Salesforce relies on the server, your CI/CD pipeline will take longer to build and test things.